# Custom error Duplicate entry devise

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I would like to customize the user error message already registered by devise

My class of registration and this:

```
class Usuarios::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController

 def new
  super do |usuario|
   redirect_to "" 
  end
end

def create
  super do |usuario|
    usuario.prevent_login = true
  end
end

def build_resource(hash=nil)
  super
  set attributes
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by adding a devise_helper.rb in your helpers. This overrides the default Devise error messages

```
module DeviseHelper
  def devise_error_messages!
  return "" unless devise_error_messages?

  messages = resource.errors.full_messages.map { |msg| content_tag(:li, msg) }.join
  sentence = I18n.t("errors.messages.not_saved",
                  :count => resource.errors.count,
                  :resource => resource.class.model_name.human.downcase)

  html = <<-HTML
  <div id="error_explanation">
  <h2>#{sentence}</h2>
  <ul>#{messages}</ul>
  </div>
  HTML

  html.html_safe
end

def devise_error_messages?
  !resource.errors.empty?
end

end
```

[You can refer here](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/app/helpers/devise_helper.rb)